# MOSS 2007 credential prompt x3 followed by a blank web page

Tags: sharepoint, password

So I've spent most of the day trying to figure out why a MOSS 2007 site hosted on one of our servers will display fine to some client computers while others get prompted for username/password three times and then dumped to an empty white webpage.

I've already gone through and disabled the loopback checking and that didn't change anything.

I've tried using both Firefox and IE.

I've tried various versions of IE (6 and 8)

I've tried adjusting the security settings for Internet Explorer.

I've tried adding the SharePoint site URL to trusted sites.

I've tried setting IE to use "Automatic logon with current username and password"

I've made sure that the site authentication in IIS has 'Windows Authentication' enabled and 'Anonymous Authentication' disabled.

I've tried every possible solution I have managed to find, but none of them seem to work and it's left me frustrated and desperate.

What can I do to fix this or at least more accurately diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try by enabling Anonymous Authentication method from IIS. you can allow IUSR as anonymous user. Let me know if still not resolved I will make more research.

Comment: Nope. The problem persists with no change.

Comment: Enable anonymous authentication method and add user who have access of that website folder. Go to Folder Properties -> Securities and allow that user for folder permission.

Comment: That doesn't quite fit my needs. I was only able to get the local administrator account to work as the anonymous access account and still had to punch in the admin password to access the site from other machines. It's not at all an acceptable workaround from a security standpoint given the environment I'm working with.

Comment: I'm still perplexed as to why there is no issue when accessing the site from my laptop, but other computers in the office encounter issues.